# Tools for Apache Cordova - Build failing

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I have a project that in one computer works just fine, but in my company notebook, it won't compile =\ Already tried to search for this specific error in google, without success...

The detailed build log is too extensive, but the tail is:

`1>  ------ Building platform: windows
1>  Debug
1>  ------ Build configuration options: --debug
1>  Running command:   C:\KodelDynamics\BRstats.Cordova\BRstats\BRstats\bld\Debug\platforms\windows\cordova\build.bat --debug --archs=anycpu --win
1>  MSBuildToolsPath: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\
1>  Applying Platform Config...
1>  Building project:   C:\KodelDynamics\BRstats.Cordova\BRstats\BRstats\bld\Debug\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows.jsproj
1>      Configuration : debug
1>      Platform      : anycpu
1>    CordovaApp.Windows -> C:\KodelDynamics\BRstats.Cordova\BRstats\BRstats\bld\Debug\platforms\windows\AppPackages\CordovaApp.Windows_1.0.0.0_anycpu_debug_Test\CordovaApp.Windows_1.0.0.0_anycpu_debug.appx
1>    CordovaApp.Windows -> C:\KodelDynamics\BRstats.Cordova\BRstats\BRstats\bld\Debug\platforms\windows\AppPackages\CordovaApp.Windows_1.0.0.0_anycpu_debug.appxupload
1>    Your package has been successfully created.
1>  Command finished with error code 0: C:\KodelDynamics\BRstats.Cordova\BRstats\BRstats\bld\Debug\platforms\windows\cordova\build.bat --debug,--archs=anycpu,--win`

NOTE: Installing the above package using powershell works fine.

`1>  ------ Copying back to project: Windows-AnyCPU
1>  ------ Copied platforms\windows\build\windows\Debug\anycpu\AppxManifest.xml to C:\KodelDynamics\BRstats.Cordova\BRstats\BRstats\bin\Windows-AnyCPU\Debug\AppxManifest.xml
1>  RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
1>Done executing task "MdaVsCli" -- FAILED.
1>Done building target "BuildMDA" in project "BRstats.jsproj" -- FAILED.`

Can't find what the hell is "Maximum call stack size exceeded" =\

Any directions would be highly appreciated

Comment: which version of cordova are you using ?

Comment: Latest... Figured out: One of my machines has a D: drive, so config.xml has a <vs:packageOutputPath>D:\SomeFolder</vs:packageOutputPath>
In this notebook, I don't have a D: drive, so the build failed. There is no clear indication on logs, but creating a common folder (like C:\Temp\Something) fixed the problem. =\